# how can I draw CVCV structures?

Tags: arrows

I need to get the following output:
[image]

So far, I just realized the CVCV structure as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} 
C$_{1}$ & V$_{1}$ & C$_{2}$ & V$_{2}$  & C$_{3}$ & V$_{3}$ & C$_{4}$ & V$_{4}$\\ 
$ \mid $ & & $ \mid $  &  & $ \mid $  & $ \mid $  & $ \mid $\\ 
s &  $ \leftarrow $ & k & & w & i & n \\  
& & & & &  & & j 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I improve this? How can I draw the arrow from the 'j' to C5?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a fragment of code, it's better to put the fragment into a complete document that people can play with.

Comment: If you need to draw full syllable structure diagrams, you might find https://github.com/amunn/syllable-struc-forest/ useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to my question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, row sep=1em, column sep={2em,between origins}, row 3/.style={font=\scshape}] 
{ 
|(C1)| C\textsubscript{1} & |(V1)| V\textsubscript{1} & 
|(C2)| C\textsubscript{2} & |(V2)| V\textsubscript{2}
& |(C3)| C\textsubscript{3} & |(V3)| V\textsubscript{3}
& |(C4)| C\textsubscript{4} & |(V4)| V\textsubscript{4} & |(C5)| C\textsubscript{5} & |(V5)| V\textsubscript{5} & |(C6)| C\textsubscript{6} & |(V6)| V\textsubscript{6}\\
|(c1)| s    & 
        & |(c2)| k & & |(c3)| w & 
        |(v3)|i & |(c4)| n & & & |(v5)| i & |(c6)| n\\
             & 
        &  & &  &  & & |(f)| j & & & & &\\
    };     
    
\draw [-] (C1) to (c1); 
\draw [-](C2) to (c2); 
\draw [-] (C3) to (c3);
\draw [-] (V3) to (v3);
\draw [-] (C4) to (c4);
\draw [-] (C5) to (f);
\draw [-] (V5) to (v5);
\draw [-] (C6) to (c6);



\draw [->] (c2) to (c1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a job for TikZ-cd:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4pt, math mode=false]
    C\textsubscript{1}\ar[d, dash] & V\textsubscript{1} & C\textsubscript{2}\ar[d, dash] & V\textsubscript{2} & C\textsubscript{3}\ar[d, dash] & V\textsubscript{3}\ar[d, dash] & C\textsubscript{4}\ar[d, dash] & V\textsubscript{4}& C\textsubscript{5} & V\textsubscript{5}\ar[d, dash]& C\textsubscript{6}\ar[d, dash] & V\textsubscript{6}\\[-6pt] 
    s & & k\ar[ll] & & w & i & n &&& i & n\\[-20pt]  
    & & & & & & & j\ar[uur, bend right, red] 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also create a new command, for convenience, avoiding writing `\textsubscript` every time (suggested by Barbara Beaton).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\scv}[2][C]{#1\textsubscript{#2}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4pt, math mode=false]
    \scv{1}\ar[d, dash] & \scv[V]{1} & \scv{2}\ar[d, dash] & \scv[V]{2} & \scv{3}\ar[d, dash] & \scv[V]{3}\ar[d, dash] & \scv{4}\ar[d, dash] & \scv[V]{4}& \scv{5} & \scv[V]{5}\ar[d, dash]& \scv{6}\ar[d, dash] & \scv[V]{6}\\[-6pt] 
    s & & k\ar[ll] & & w & i & n &&& i & n\\[-20pt]  
    & & & & & & & j\ar[uur, bend right, red] 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Linguists use `gb4e`. It allows you to have access to `_` and `^` in text mode directly (suggested by Alan Munn).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4pt, math mode=false]
    C_{1}\ar[d, dash] & V_{1} & C_{2}\ar[d, dash] & V_{2} & C_{3}\ar[d, dash] & V_{3}\ar[d, dash] & C_{4}\ar[d, dash] & V_{4}& C_{5} & V_{5}\ar[d, dash]& C_{6}\ar[d, dash] & V_{6}\\[-6pt] 
    s & & k\ar[ll] & & w & i & n &&& i & n\\[-20pt]  
    & & & & & & & j\ar[uur, bend right, red] 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output is always the same as the first example.

Comment: +1 since this is linguistics and not math, you may want to add `math mode=false` (and fix the subscripts appropriately).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you! I don't know what a CVCV structure is, of course. I'll correct at once

Comment: @AlanMunn Corrected!